# Twitterizer Problems

Tags: twitter, twitterizer

I am trying to figure out if twitterizer is still relevant. The library looks really old. And the current project i am working on uses it. I am using the following code...

```
private static OAuthTokens OAuthTokens()
        {
            var accessToken = "<insert>";
            var accessTokenSecret = "<insert>";
            var consumerKey = "<insert>";
            var consumerSecret = "<insert>";

            return new OAuthTokens
            {
                ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
                AccessToken = accessToken,
                AccessTokenSecret = accessTokenSecret
            };
        }
```

if i do the following call

```
var responseFollowersIds = TwitterFriendship.FollowersIds(credentials, new UsersIdsOptions()
            {
                UseSSL = true,
                APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/",
                ScreenName = screenName
            });
```

I can see that i have followers and that the request being made looks like this

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=screenname&cursor=-1
```

notice that i set the `APIBaseAddress` to the latest version, but if i try and get the followers i use the following

```
var responseFollowers = TwitterFriendship.Followers(credentials, new FollowersOptions
            {
                ScreenName = screenName,
                UseSSL = true,
                APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/",
            });
```

But then i get an error

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

upon further investigation i realized that `TwitterFriendship.Followers` request url is wrong and that is buried deep in the `twitterizer` code.
The request made is

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/followers.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=screenname
```

and should be

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json
```

according to the new `twitter` documentation.
Is there an easy way to fix it?

Comment: Do you consider using another library or do you want to fix Twitterizer?

Comment: I wanted to fix the twitterizer, but the juice was worth the squeeze. So i ended up using tweetinvi. It is a lot nicer to work with

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but just in case anyone faces this problem again. You can easily fix it by modifiying the code of Twitterizer at `\Methods\User\FollowersCommand.cs`, look for the constructor and change the URL of the method:

```
public FollowersCommand(OAuthTokens tokens, FollowersOptions options)
: base(HTTPVerb.GET, "followers/list.json", tokens, options)
```

Comment: That is true, but they should fix it. You should not need to go into the code and change it. Better yet do a pull request and fix it so that you can parse in the correct url. Harding coding urls are just bad